# Kinect as a Webcam Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kinect, openkinect

Is there any known way to use the Kinect as a webcam inside a Linux environment, perhaps using openkinect to some capacity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133426/kinect-as-a-webcam

Comment: @MattStokes Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Casually late to the party, but here's what I had to do with my Kinect v1 (xbox 360).

### Video

Dunno why the module doesn't load automatically when the Kinect is plugged in, but doing it manualy gives us the Xbox NUI Camera at `/dev/video0` which then shows up anywhere you'd expect (cheese, vlc, browser, etc...):

```
sudo modprobe gspca_kinect
```

Note that this isn't persistent so you'll need to type it after restarting the computer, or if you unload the module manually.

### Audio

The microphone array won't show up in pulseaudio unless we upload a (specific?) firmware to the Kinect. Someone worked out how to do that and in theory it should be as simple as:

```
sudo apt install kinect-audio-setup
```

In practice tho, the md5 check sum of microsoft's firmware has changed so the install fails. To fix it, we need to open the script in an editor and update the md5 sum:

```
sudo micro /usr/sbin/kinect_fetch_fw
```

Then replace the `SDK_MD5` value at the top of the script, by `945806927702b2c47c32125ab9a80344` (as of time of writing, but that might change again).

Once that's done just run apt again and it should finish the install fine.

```
sudo apt install kinect-audio-setup
```

The install will also write a udev file to upload the firmware automatically whenever the Kinect is plugged in.